# Map reduce output to oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, mapreduce

We are developing a network monitoring tool which continously monitor and collect cpu usage%, memory usage% data from the configured systems. We currently put the data into oracle db. Our intention is to produce graphical reports based on the data .For example CPU usage for Last 12 Hrs will show a line graph with 12 plotting points.ie, interval is 1 hour.
Still then the performance is bit slow. Our plan is to increase plotting poins . ie, we plot graphs wit interval 10 sec. ,30 sec, ... With oracle querying it seems to be harder.

So we plan to use hadoop for storing time series monitoring data and shedule a map reduce job to obtain averages for various time intervals.One option I think is to read output directly from hdfs. It make our programmers to rewrite the graphloading section.Can we write this output to **oracle** database so that we can readily query this data ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Worst case scenario, write your own `OutputFormat`.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? This is a reasonable question. My suggestion is to use Sqoop or write a custom OutputFormat.

Comment: @DonaldMiner sorry, but this is a question like "Can you google for me how I can insert data from MapReduce to a relational database". He has to do the research beforehand, not only to mention that there are more than a dozen already answered questions on that topic here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Since we do not know exactly your skill level and thus cannot judge what you can or cannot do, this could be considered opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to move data from HDFS to database using sqoop. It takes out the heavy-lifting you'd have to do manually.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Oracle Loader for Hadoop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37231_01/doc.20/e36961/olh.htm). It appears to be a free library from Oracle for doing essentially exactly what you are looking for. It appears to come with an OutputFormat that will write directly to an Oracle instance.